# C++ socket server receive msg from Java client, but not otherwise

Tags: c#, java, android, c++, sockets

I have just started to learn C++ and Java. For my first project, I made a C++ TCP socket server. Unfortunately, it don't work as I expected.

How it works:

If I start my Java **Android** client, my C++ server instantly detects a new connection.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intrologin_layout);
    client = new TCPClient("10.0.2.2", 50120);

    try {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    client.startClient();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sending bytes also works through the Java Android client:

```
output = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
output.write(Packet);
output.flush();
```

My C++ server returns automaticly received packets in the console, which works pretty well,
but then I try to send a reply back, the recv worked on my C++ client but here is the main problem, it don't on my Java client **until I close the server process or the socket.**

C++ serverside:

```
pd->SendPacket("BYE\0", 4);
```

...

```
void Desc::SendPacket(const char* c_cpBuffer, int Length)
{
  int BytesSended = send(m_Socket, c_cpBuffer, Length, 0);

  if (BytesSended <= 0)
  {
    printf("Packet send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
  }
}
```

Java Android clientside:

```
public void startClient() throws Exception
{
    connectionSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
    output = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

    messageReceiver = new Thread() {
        public void run()
        {
            while(connectionSocket.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    String receivedMessage = input.readLine();
                    input.toString();

                    if(receivedMessage != null) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR");
                        Log.d("Received Message: ", receivedMessage);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    messageReceiver.start();
}
```

I stuck in this problem since weeks, thank you.

Comment: Maybe I don't explained it clear enough, the Java Android client, receive the message only if I kill the C++ server process or shutdown the socket.

Comment: input.toString(); doesn't exists in the actual code.

Comment: @mah Just tryed it out, doesn't worked. Though if I kill the process, it gonna receive it. :(

Comment: @mah Thank you very much, it was the true direction. Finally, the answer from the user anonymous was correct: pd->SendPacket("BYE\n", 4); works like a charm.

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved. I'll delete my prior comments though as they really didn't provide any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have input.readLine() and that would not return unless a line feed is detected. If your server sends messages that are terminated by line feed, your java client should pick that up.

The following is code printing what is received from server. Use BufferedInputStream rather than BufferedReader. Haven't tested the code below but it will read up to 10 bytes from server each time. Because it is buffered, I am not sure how "real time" it is. For example, server sends 3 characters then sleep for 5 seconds and sends 7 chars. Whether client will receive 3 chars immediately and print that followed by 7 chars after 5 seconds or client will wait and receive 10 chars after 5 seconds and print all 10 at once, you need to test that.

```
BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputSream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] buffer = new byte[10]; // 10 bytes buffer
int bytesRead = 0;
while( (bytesRead=input.read(buffer)) !=-1 ) { // read up to 10 bytes
    String str = new String(buffer,0,bytesRead); // convert bytes to String using default encoding
    System.out.println("Data received: " + str);
}
```

Comment: input.toString(); doesn't exists in the actual code. I added it by mistake, but it's not relevant here. What is a line feed by the way?

Comment: Line feed is the character "\n".

Comment: Just found out what it is, I gonna try it out thanks.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much mate. It works! So simple, unbelievble.

Comment: I got one question left, is there any way to do it without line feed, maybe another function?

Comment: You can read the raw bytes as they come in and keep printing it. I'll update answer with this.

Comment: Alright, I will await your update. Thanks, such helpful ppl here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at the same problem for Month, even redo whole project differently still didn't helped me, and the problem is so simple. `in.readline()` function expects end of line to continue, so you should append it to your buffer.

```
 pd->SendPacket("BYE\0\n", 4);
```

Hope it helped, like it helped me.